# LinearLayout doesn't display all components

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm using a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"` but there are two components that I can't see when the app run... This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/a" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/d" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/b" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/c" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know where the problem can be. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Which ones you cannot see? Why a `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`. Is it really needed?

Comment: You're using your layouts in a bad way: why is a `RelativeLayout` there? Try to find what makes the `LinearLayout`'s children not expanding.

Answer (score 1):

Provide `weight` attribute to all inside `LinearLayout` by using

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Check this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/a" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/d" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/b" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/c" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, that would expand `LinearLayout`s children. Although I still don't get why a `RelativeLayout` is there ^^

Comment: That's true its useless